# Python Shell and Terminal acting differently to pyspotify module

Tags: python, module, terminal, spotify

I actually think I should not ask this question here but I ran out of options and desperately looking for help.

I have a script that uses pyspotify module.

```
from spotify import ArtistBrowser, Link, ToplistBrowser, SpotifyError
```

When I run this through the Shell it gives the following error

```
ImportError: No module named _spotify
```

However I can run this through terminal with no errors.
"which python" command gives the following location

```
/usr/local/bin/python
```

os.getcwd() command gives a different location

```
/Users/paulmiles/Documents/pyspotify/examples
```

Both versions use the following version

```
ActivePython 2.7.2.5 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 24 2011, 12:20:15) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
```

Can this be a signal of anything? I am on OS X 10.8.3.

Any ideas about what may be going on and how to fix this, is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try running `import sys; print sys.path` in both environments.

Comment: Giving different results in different orders. Also while Terminal has 18 items, Python shell has 19. Will that help if I send the output?

Comment: What is `sys.executable`? What commands do you execute exactly when youwrite 'run this through the Shell'

Comment: @alexChamberlain Both have the same path:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

Not sure if I understand your question. I have a python script that I am either running with IDLE or going to terminal and  running "python myScript.py"